# Reshape content of multiple lists of matrices into one dataframe

Tags: r

I have four lists of matrices(`intdiv1`,`intdiv2`,`intdiv3`,`intdiv4`). The first element of the list is a matrix of diversity values `div` (row 1: observed values of diversity `obs`and row2: estimated values of diversity `est`), the second element is a matrix of  observed and estimated standard errors `se`, the third element of the list is the Lower Confidence intervals `LCI` for observed and estimated values and the fourth is the upper confidence interval `UCI`for the estimated and observed diversities.  Here is an example of one list:

```
intdiv1<-

$div
     q1 q2 q3 q4
 obs 1  4   5 2 
 est 0  2   3 6 


$sd
     q1 q2 q3 q4
 obs 2  4  4  2 
 est 0  2  1  2 

$LCI
     q1   q2  q3  q4
 obs .1  .2  .2  .4
 est  0   2   1   2 

$UCI
     q1  q2  q3  q4
 obs .2  .4  .4  .2 
 est  0   2   1   4
```

I have four lists with the same elements for the four different regions I am examining. I would like to make the contents of the four lists one dataframe that combines the results of the list into a dataframe. The rows of each matrix would become their own variable in the dataframe . The output would appear as follows (Note: The values will not match the values in the example list since I use the `sample` function for the output:

```
output<- data.frame(list= 
                     c("intdiv1","intdiv1","intdiv1","intdiv1", 
                       "intdiv2","intdiv2","intdiv2","intdiv2", 
                       "intdiv3","intdiv3","intdiv3","intdiv3", 
                       "intdiv4","intdiv4","intdiv4","intdiv4"), 
                q=rep(c("1","2","3","4"),4),   
                 div.obs=sample(c(1:50), 16, replace=TRUE),  
                 div.est= sample(c(1:50), 16,replace=TRUE), 
                 sd.obs=sample(c(0:5), 16,replace=TRUE), 
                 sd.est=sample(c(0:5), 16,replace=TRUE),                      
                  LCI.obs=sample(c(1:50), 16,replace=TRUE), 
                 LCI.est=sample(c(1:50), 16,replace=TRUE),  
                 UCI.obs= sample(c(1:50), 16,replace=TRUE), 
                 UCI.est=sample(c(1:50), 16,replace=TRUE))
```

I have tried the following to make a single list a dataframe:

```
df.intdiv1<- lapply(seq_along(intdivdf1), function (i) {
data.frame(obs.div=intdivdf1[[1]][1,], 
         obs.se=intdivdf1[[2]][1,],
         obs.LCI=intdivdf1[[3]][1,],
         obs.UCI=intdivdf1[[4]][1,],
         est.div=intdivdf1[[1]][2,], 
         est.se=intdivdf1[[2]][2,],
         est.LCI=intdivdf1[[3]][2,],
         est.UCI=intdivdf1[[4]][2,]
         )
   })       

 intdivall<- rbind(df.intdiv1, df.intdiv2, df.intdiv3, df.intdiv4)
```

However I get an error on the first function and don't think my method is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
J <- function(x) t(rbind(x$div, x$sd, x$LCI, x$UCI))

output<- data.frame(
  List=rep(c("intdiv1","intdiv2","intdiv3","intdiv4"), each=4),
  q=rep(c("1","2","3","4"),4))
# or:
# output <- expand.grid(q=1:4, List=paste0("intdiv", 1:4))

output <- cbind(output, rbind(J(intdiv1), J(intdiv2), J(intdiv3), J(intdiv4)))
```

If you want you can rename the columns of the dataframe.